# IntelliJ Idea LanternaGriffon Doesn't Recognize Griffon Project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, griffon, lanterna

I just made my first Griffon project, using [lazybones](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/). I chose `griffon-lanterna-groovy` for my template, and I then removed `pom.xml` and `maven/` as I will be using Gradle. I then run `gradle build test run` and everything looked good. (it ran, build succeeded, etc.)

Next, I opened the project in IntelliJ and I've tried this in a variety of ways. No matter what I do, it IntelliJ doesn't recognize that this is a Griffon project.

I am using the latest stable version of all these library's, and I'm using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition. I'm to to lazybones, Griffon, and lanterna, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just realized the last commit was 4 years ago.... Oh dear.....

Comment: Not true. The last commit was done 4 days ago, on May 6th 2017 https://github.com/griffon/griffon/commit/240ed99d28ee9e8659bb7d27920c6f4a88755712

Answer (score 1):

Griffon 2.x applications are either regular Gradle or Maven projects, you **do not** need an specific Griffon IDE plugin. IntelliJ ships with a Griffon plugin that's only compatible with Griffon 1.x projects. Do not use this plugin.

Refer to http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html#_tutorial_1_4

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I'll check this out later. (this weekend probably)