# Lanterna Groovy SwingBuilder

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder, lanterna

Is there any way I can use [lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/) in Groovy using [SwingBuilder?](http://groovy-lang.org/swing.html) Or at least something similar? I like Groovy, and I would like to use it to make a command line app, but it would be nice if it were concise and in Groovy.

Comment: Yea you can use it or you can do with Griffon which is a project from the groovy comunity. https://github.com/griffon/griffon

Comment: @Raphael yeah... I found this https://github.com/griffon/griffon-lanterna-plugin, but I can't get it to work. Last commit 4 years ago. (Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872688/intellij-idea-lanternagriffon-doesnt-recognize-griffon-project)